# To enable TLS 1.2 on SharePoint 2013 environment

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a Requirement to migrate from TLS 1.1 to TLS 1.2 and in order to do that i have a prerequisite to install Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 or above and my server is WINDOWS 2008 R2 SP1 so i want to know if i want to install .NET framework 4.6 or higher should i need to consider any dependencies on current environment? or just go ahead and uninstall .net framework 4.5 and install 4.6?

Answer (score 0):

You don't uninstall .NET 4.5, just install .NET 4.6. Follow the full instructions are at [Enable TLS and SSL support in SharePoint 2013](https://docs.microsoft.com/SharePoint/security-for-sharepoint-server/enable-tls-and-ssl-support-in-sharepoint-2013).